Wkhtmltopdf is not repeating table headers
I have a very long table and the table header is supposed to be repeating on each page break, but it's not.
Furthermore, on some page breaks rows get casually cut in the middle along with their text.
I tried CTRL+P on the html document and the header loops fine. Weasyprint worked fine too but I have Wkhtmltopdf as a requirement.
I tried adding this to my css template, but it didn't help.
tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}
table {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

Update: I solved (?) the issue by updating Wkhtmltopdf to one with patched QT. But now, what used to take 15 seconds to compile takes 2+ minutes. However, everything is formatted properly.

Update: I solved (?) the issue by updating Wkhtmltopdf to one with patched QT. But now, what used to take 15 seconds to compile takes 2+ minutes. However, everything is formatted properly.
